# Is it possible to toggle between Ubuntu and Windows 7 with the click of a button?

Tags: windows

I would like to know if there is any kind of software that will allow me to have Ubuntu and Windows side-by-side and toggle between them instantly.

Say, for instance, I'm on Windows then by clicking on a button, Windows would be suspended and Ubuntu would be initiated (and vice versa).

Is this possible/available?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to easily switch between windows and Ubuntu OS's was by running Ubuntu on virtual machine softwares like VMware,virtualbox,etc.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: impossible. A virtual machine is the closest you can get to that.

Long answer: an operating system requires constant access to the hardware. The operating system needs to be built to allow dynamic switching in mind for such a thing be come to reality.

P.S.: With an SSD, you can hibernate between operating systems pretty darn fast, but that will dramatically reduce the longevity of your SSD.